# in python multithreading, what is the use of mutex lock along with join in the same program

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, mutex

I came across a few programs where mutex lock along with thread join is used.

The same variable is being edited (list in this case) by multiple threads.
Each thread invokes another thread, so its sort of a parent-child relationship.
thread join had to be used to ensure sync.

When a thread join ensures that unless the called/child thread completes, the calling/parent thread cannot execute, is there a usecase for adding mutex acquire/release for the list variable ?

Below program recursively searches for files with name 'json' within any specified directory

```
import os
from os.path import isdir, join
from threading import Thread, Lock

mutex = Lock()
search_result = []

def search_files(root, searchfile):
    search_threads = []
    for file in os.listdir(root):
        fullpath = join(root,file)
        if searchfile in fullpath:
            mutex.acquire()
            search_result.append(fullpath)
            mutex.release()
        if isdir(fullpath):
            t = Thread(target=search_files, args=([fullpath, searchfile]))         
            t.start()
            search_threads.append(t)
    
    for t in search_threads:
        t.join()
            

root_path = '/users/kn/'
searchfile = 'json'

t = Thread(target=search_files, args=([root_path, searchfile]))
t.start()
t.join()

print(f' Num files with name {searchfile} = {len(search_result)}')
```

Whether I use the mutex or not, I get the same result.

Trying to understand the use of mutex along with join in this example.

Answer (score 0):

A mutex (short for "mutual exclusion") is used to ensure that a shared resource or a variable is only accessed by one thread at a time, preventing [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software).

In the given code, the "search_result" list is a shared resource that can be accessed and modified by multiple threads.

The join() method will ensure that the parent thread waits for his children to complete their execution before the parent continues. It helps synchronize the order of execution for threads, but it doesn't protect the shared resource from concurrent access. It's dangerous because it can lead to unexcepted behavior or even data corruption.

The "search_files" function can be called concurrently by multiple threads as it is being used as the target for all the new threads. Thus, each of these threads can possibly find a matching file and append it to the "search_result" list.

By the way, you said that you get the same result whether you use a mutex or not. This is likely because the directory structure you're testing with and the number of threads involved in your test case might not be large enough to trigger a race condition.

Keep in mind that : it's still a good practice to use mutex when dealing with shared resources in a multithreaded program to avoid potential issues in more complex scenarios !

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Teroaz
What I missed was that there are multiple parent threads running parallelly, and hence multiple parallelly running child threads as well. So the mutex is needed.

Comment: With pleasure ! :)